# Filter data frame by combination of 2 variables that appear in other data frame

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, unique

Suppose i have two data frames, DF1 and DF2

```
DF1:

CustomerID     Name      PurchaseCode
1              Drue       1234
2              David      1222
3              Chris      1333
5              Kenny      3122
```

And

```
DF2:
CustomerID         Name      PurchaseCode
1                  Drue       1234
4                  Gimmy      1222
3                  Chris      1333
```

Now i want to filter DF1 by the **Unique** combination of `CustomerID` and `PurchaseCode` in DF2

So my filtered data frame would look like that:

```
CustomerID     Name      PurchaseCode
 1             Drue       1234
 3             Chris      1333
```

Notice that 'Gimmy' from DF2 has `PurchaseCode`that appears in DF1, but his `CustomerID` does not match to the unique combination in DF1, so 'Gimmy' will not appear in the filtered data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `anti_join(DF1, DF2, by = c("PurchaseCode", "CustomerID")`. Also definitely read the documentation on joins in dplyr.

Comment: None of the Joins in dplyr gets me the desired output. Consider that my problem is more complicated, so i tried to simplify it with my question. is there any way to **filter** one data frame by other?